# Generating vector elements with a random-based command, Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm trying to construct a vector with n-elements. I want each of my elements, x_5, to be defined as such :

x_5 = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + (x_3)^2 + (x_4)^2

where each x_i = randn. This is the script I am using right now :

```
x_1 = randn;
x_2 = randn;
x_3 = randn;
x_4 = randn;
for x_5 = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + (x_3)^2 + (x_4)^2
    n=1000000
end
v=repelem(x_5,1000000);
```

I want to implement a loop command, so that each x_5 corresponds to a specific operation for x_5. That is, each x_5 in my vector is generated by my algorithm *individually*. With this script, x_5 is generated only once, and my vector is then filled with 1.000.000 copies of this same result. Instead, I would like to make 1.000.000 calculations for x_5, *and then* fill my vector with these results.

Other suggestions besides making

```
for x_5 = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + (x_3)^2 + (x_4)^2
    n=1000000
end
```

work are also welcome. I'm not sure whether a loop command is the best choice here, but I would like to learn about it with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop iterates only once and the numbers are generated only once. You have to move the logic into the loop:

```
v = zeros(1, 1000000);
parfor n = 1:length(v)
    v(n) = sum(randn(1, 4).^2);
end
```

You can reduce the code to

```
v = arrayfun(@(x) sum(randn(1, 4).^2), zeros(1, 1000000));
```